# Cannot access a website from  Firefox

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, chrome

I'm trying to access [www.belgacom.be](http://www.belgacom.be) using Firefox from my Archlinux system and I get the following error:

```
Firefox can't find the server at www.belgacom.be
```

When I use Chromium, it works perfectly.

I tried deleting the `~/.mozilla` directory, with no success. I've also tried running Firefox from another user session, with no luck.

I'm running the latest version of Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: What abourt other websites, do these work?

Comment: Yes all other websites are working

Comment: What does `host www.belgacom.be` return from your machine?  Does Chromium have a proxy configured?

Comment: What are your proxy settings in Chrome and Firefox? What is your DNS configuration (if you don't know, start by posting the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`)?

Comment: host www.belgacom.be
www.belgacom.be has address 195.13.15.25
Host www.belgacom.be not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain home
search home
nameserver 192.168.1.1

Comment: What are the DNS settings on your router?

Comment: Useless use of cat. On topic: Change your resolv.conf to 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 and try again. @Unode is probably on the right trail.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on a fresh Archlinux installation.

My resolv.conf contains only

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

(plus a few comments)
It's the address of my "box" (router, modem...). It works perfectly for every other domain (Belgacom is my ISP).

I tried a ping but it fails. I installed Chromium to test and it's working but it's not working with Epiphany, so I guess it's not a problem with Firefox. Other computers (on Ubuntu) using the same address as nameserver can access to this domain.

A dig gives me this result :

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.1-P1 <<>> belgacom.be
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17483
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;belgacom.be.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
belgacom.be.        1643    IN  A   195.13.15.25

;; Query time: 67 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Jul 23 02:57:59 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

I fixed this problem by adding 2 old dns servers to /etc/resolv.conf :

```
nameserver 195.238.2.21
nameserver 195.238.2.22
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works on the same machine under a different browser check if you have proxies enabled or if any of the installed addons is interfering with DNS resolution.

Since you already removed your profile folder and even tried different user sessions, my bet goes to preinstalled addons or proxies.

Close any firefox instance and try `firefox -safe-mode`. If this doesn't work, check that you don't have any proxy enabled.

If neither works, I've no idea what could be wrong.

Comment: I tried running firefox in safe mode with no success. I don't have any proxy

Comment: Just out of curiosity, that address wouldn't happen to be the place where you work? I'm wondering if you have something on your `/etc/hosts` file or in the network that makes the address resolve locally instead of via the external address...

Comment: No, I'm trying to access it from home.